# why is my variable that is declared outside and before the function, being 'referenced before assignment'?

Tags: python

```
placesLeft = 9

def playerTurn():
  whereToGo = int(input("Where would you like to place your piece? "))
  while True:
    if whereToGo in row1:
      row1.insert(whereToGo - 1, "X")
      del row1[whereToGo]
      placesLeft = placesLeft - 1

playerTurn()
```

This isn't my full code obviously but the function is really big and I didn't think it was relevant to include. Is there something I'm missing with the scope laws in Python?

Comment: You can reference a variable from an outer scope, but as you soon as you try to assign a new value to it you're shadowing the outer name with a new local variable -- and in this case you're assigning a value based on that same local variable (which hasn't been defined yet, hence the error).  You can "fix" this by using `global` or `nonlocal`, but it'd be better to avoid this pattern and instead pass it in as a mutable parameter.

Comment: Come on, "referenced before assignment" gives 157,000 hits on Google, with 2261 hits on StackOverflow alone. Please Google your error messages before posting a question. Most of the top hits answer your question.